# Mount SD media in read-write mode doesn't appear to work?

Tags: mount, fstab, sd-card

I have this in my `/etc/fstsab`:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sd  auto user,noauto,rw,x-gvfs-name=sd%20card 0 0
```

But when I try to write anything into the `/media/sd`:

```
[mei@localhost Documenti]$ cp mare.odt /media/sd/.
cp: impossibile creare il file regolare '/media/sd/./mare.odt': Permission denied
```

I tried also to force permissions on the destination:

```
[root@localhost Documenti]# chmod -R 777 /media/sd/
[root@localhost Documenti]# ll /media/
totale 40
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root  4096  4 nov  2017 oldhome
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 32768  1 gen  1970 sd
```

I tried also mounting directly by hand with

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sd -v
```

No luck. Any hint?

Comment: What if you do the mounting by hand via `mount` command and use `-v` switch?

Comment: Not familiar with the `x-gvfs-name` option, but is it looking for an exact match, starts with, or substring anywhere? although if that part wasn't working i'd imagine it wouldn't mount at all...

Comment: When you tried to `cp` the file to `/media/sd` what showed up in the `dmesg`?

Comment: Does the SD card have a write-protect switch that might have been turned on accidentally?

Comment: No, the SD card is not write-protected by the switch. Same behaviour happens for USB stick. Only root is able to copy...

Comment: @sim no message in dmesg when copying. Mounting with -v as root nothing changes...

Answer (score 1):

After carefully reading the man page of mount and experimenting on the shell with various options of mount, found a solution.

It seems that the right entry in the fstab is this

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/sd  vfat user,noauto,rw,umask=0000 0 0
```

It sounds like that:

- `auto` is not enough, better to specify the FS type
- `umask` select available permissions (in this case for all users)